# ¿Existe alguna función matemática capaz de subir/bajar el volumen en función de la posición del jugador con la fuente de sonido?

Tags: c++, matemáticas, math, game, sfml

Estoy programando un pequeño juego 2D y llevo ya un tiempo intentando que, en función de la posición del jugador frente a la fuente de sonido, el volumen sea mayor o menor (teniendo un máximo definido).

Por cada frame se calcula la distancia entre ambos objetos y se guarda en la variable *distancia*.

Tras analizar un poco el problema he escrito la siguente función:

```
if(distancia <= rango)
{
    volumen = volumenMax - (distancia / volumenMax);
}
```

Sin embargo el resultado es extraño. Si pongo volumenes pequeños ni se nota, y si pongo un rango grande el efecto desaparece a mitad de camino.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna función matemática que sea capaz de realizar este cálculo correctamente.

Comment: Alomejor te sirve la formula del efecto doopler. 
  https://www.fisicalab.com/apartado/efecto-doppler

Comment: El efecto doopler se da cuando la fuente de sonido está en movimiento en relación al oyente.

Comment: Vestelion, estás haciendo un decaimiento de volumen lineal, pero el decaimiento debería ser cuadrático (ya que [decae con el cuadrado de la distancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_la_inversa_del_cuadrado).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster He estado investigando un poco sobre esta ley y por lo que he visto, de ser así, el volumen sería el resultado de la siguiente ecuación v = 1/d^2 (v -> volumen, d -> distancia). Lo he probado y el volumen es prácticamente 0 siempre que no esté a una distancia exageradamente corta de la fuente de sonido (mas allá de una distancia de 10 ya no se oye nada). No sé si esa era la ecuación a la que te referías.

Comment: @Vestelion no se del tema nada más allá de que el sonido decae con el cuadrado de la distancia. El efecto que describes puede deberse a que usas enteros en lugar de flotantes para el cálculo o que tienes errores en el cálculo... es difícil de adivinarlo sin ver nada de código.

Answer (score 0):

> Si pongo volumenes pequeños ni se nota, y si pongo un rango grande el efecto desaparece a mitad de camino.

El problema es que no tienes en cuenta el rango para calcular el volumen, sólo la distancia. Esto significa que cuando la `distancia` sea igual a `volumenMax` al cuadrado, el sonido desaparecerá sí o sí, dando igual si el rango era más grande.

Si quieres que el volumen sea 0 cuando la distancia sea igual al rango, y en medio vaya cambiando, prueba con la siguiente fórmula:

```
volumen = volumenMax * (rango - distancia)/rango
```

Aunque esta debería funcionar como quieres , he sacado esta otra fórmula que también tiene las mismas propiedades pero decrece de manera un poco más orgánica (de manera curva, no linear):

```
volumen = - volumenMax * (distancia-rango) / (rango * (distancia+1))
```

Con ambas ecuaciones se cumple que:

- Cuando la distancia es igual al rango, el volumen es 0.
- Cuando la distancia es 0, es volumen es el máximo.